# how to convert and retrive timespan in sql server without losing data?

Tags: c#, sql-server

i want to store time span from c# to SQL Server 2012 .
i want to know what is the best SQL Server data type to store it?

for example if i convert my time span to string it will be: 2083.07:00:00

information about my time span:

```
 Ticks  1799964000000000    long
 TotalDays  2083.2916666666665  double
 TotalHours 49999.0 double
 TotalMilliseconds  179996400000.0  double
 TotalSeconds   179996400.0 double
```

now what is the best SQL Server data type to store this value.
it is very important to me that do not losing and data and when i fetched this data and convert it to time span again this result will equal to first data value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the `Time` data type in SQL Server or store the number of ticks in the `TimeSpan` in a `bigint` column.